# Mac Safari Crash after website load

Tags: wordpress, macos, web, safari

I have an own wordpress website and every time i go on this site:

http://produkt-kenner.de/neue-erfahrungen-kostenloser-20-euro-amazon-gutschein-code/

My site crashes on Safari for MacOS. Im on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6. On my other macbook i have the same problem and my brother too with his mac.

[image: Crash Notification]

If i try to load the website with google chrome it refreshes the site a few times.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: I already accepted the cookie information, there for i won't show up to me and the share buttons are on the left side

Comment: You have lots of errors, please check your console in Chrome. Fonts can't be loaded, hundreds of `Uncaught TypeError`s. Facebook connect is saying the domain is invalid …